# Write.table using looped variable in a for loop

Tags: r

I have a very stupid question. It has been already asked, but none of the solutions provided seem to work with me. 
I am looping over a list containing different data frames, to perform an analysis and save an output file named differently for each input data frame. The name would be something like originalname_output.txt.
I wrote this piece of code which seems to work fine (does all the analysis in the correct ways), but gives an error when coming to the write.table part.

```r
library(qqman)
library(QuASAR)

list_QuASAR <- list (Fw, Rv, tot) #all of the are dfs

for (i in list_QuASAR){
  output <- fitQuasarMpra(i[,2], i[,3], i[,4])
  print(sum(output$padj_quasar<0.1))
  qq(output$pval3, col = "black", cex = 1)
  write.table(output, paste0("quasar_output/", i, "_output.txt"), col.names = T, sep = "\t")
}
```

fitQuasarMpra is a function of a package called QuASAR. Of course the subdirectory called quasar_output already exists.

The error I am getting is:

```r
Error in file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) : 
  invalid 'description' argument
In addition: Warning message:
In if (file == "") file <- stdout() else if (is.character(file)) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

I know it's a trivial problem but I am currently stuck. I may consider to switch and use lapply, but then I may encounter the same problem and I wanted to solve this first.
Many thanks for you help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're trying to use a data frame object (`i`) as part of a file name; i.e. the data frame itself, not its name. You could try iterating over a named list instead:

```
list_QuASAR <- list (Fw = Fw,Rv = Rv,tot = tot)

for (i in names(list_QuASAR)){
  output <- fitQuasarMpra(list_QuASAR[[i]][,2], list_QuASAR[[i]][,3], list_QuASAR[[i]][,4])
  print(sum(output$padj_quasar<0.1))
  qq(output$pval3, col = "black", cex = 1)
  write.table(output, paste0("quasar_output/", i, "_output.txt"), col.names = T, sep = "\t")
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That worked as expected. Unfortunately I am still a beginner and I miss some basic knowledges like this one...